# REST | JWT | Auth: How To Verify Authorities For Secure Resources

Tags: node.js, rest, http, authentication, jwt

#### Token-Based Authentication: JWT? Check. `GET /items/:id`... How?

This is a small question, but probably a big answer, as I'm a bit new to this...

Once I have provided a client a JWT -- and they wish to obtain a resource -- what does the logic-flow of verifying Client look like?

In other words, I have a JWT *payload* such as...

```
{
    ...
    "sub": user.id
    ...
}
```

... and Client needs to access *item* `998` at `/api/items/:id`...

My current approach looks something like the following.

```
// ItemsController.lang | 'GET /api/items/:id'
var userId = jwt.decode(token).sub;
var isValid = checkUserIdInDatabase(userId);
var secureResource = ORM.findOne({ user: userId, id: request.itemId });
response.send(secureResource);
```

Along with this, when Client signs up/in, I provide them a response which looks like this...

```
{ user: { id: 998, email: 'no@username.com', preferences: [...] }, jwt: token }
```

1. Should I ever be sending `id` & `email` if I'm issuing a JWT?
2. Given that I should have middleware to check if my `jwt.sub`'s [`userId`] value exists in the database, should I use this userId as part of my query, or should Client be sending Server the userId as `request.body.userId` since it obtains it upon sign in/up?
3. Is it a no-no to assign a userId to `payload.sub`?
4. **Do I need to generate a new JWT with a new lifespan upon every request and send it to the client?**
5. What are all my security blunders, what is best practice, and what would you do?

Every tutorial I look at shows a nice & clean high-level flow stating [simply] that '*if the JWT is verified, the resource is sent to the client*'.

Can you please provide me with some direction on how all this token-based authentication stuff is supposed to work at the low-level -- namely, in order to request secure resources?

PreThanks,

Cody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solely my point of view and i am no expert, here it goes:

1) I think you should not send user ID in your response as there is not a lot of scenarios where i see that would be necessary for client to know its user id, you easily assign this to your token payload and use a middle ware like [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt)
to do the decoding and giving the user id for you.

2) Do not rely on sensitive data sent by client, if you use express-jwt then it would assign user id with every request object eg: **req.user.userId**

3) you can  assign user id and other small user session data in your payload, your client would require your secret key and to be able to decode that information , always have a strong secret key.

4) I think you should have token life span expire after a day or even less, there are scenarios where you may need to go longer i think 1 week should be maximum amount of time you should have your token life span. now you can always refresh your token and have your application check after some interval of time if its token is valid and request for refresh or new one after expiration .

5) may be these:

- Have a strong secret key.
- Use cookies to store secret key for web applications
- Keep your token life span short as possible.
- Use HTTPS protocol for APIs.
- Write a middle-ware or use already existing middle-wares for user authentication. eg: [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt)
- [jwt tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543) [tutorial2](http://www.planetnodejs.com/article/56afd59cb4827d0e00c88635/user-authentication-with-the-mean-stack) ,using [storm-path](https://stormpath.com/blog/nodejs-jwt-create-verify) and using [passport](https://blog.hyphe.me/token-based-authentication-with-node/)

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: This is a tremendous help -- thank you a bunch for taking the time to answer so thoroughly. I'm only hazy about your #3 & #5-b. Why should Client need my SECRET and why the proposition for Cookies to store SECRET? Aren't tokens used to obviate the vulnerability of Cookies, and wouldn't the use of a client-side SECRET be a risk and unnecessary, or is that latter just for decoding very sensitive & necessary data such as SSN? Many thanks.

Comment: Also, in #2, is this to assume that my "current approach" is partially on-track? Whereas, #2 suggests to employ `ORM.findOne({ req.user.userId, ... })`... is that right? I should use `req.middleware.user.id` / `jwt.sub` to map secure resources to the appropriate user?

Comment: No your secret keys should never be shared and for web applications store token in cookies not secret key

Comment: Your client is not supposed to decrypt your token all he needs to do is send you token with every request. So  never share your secret key

Comment: Perfect, thx again. I'm gonna accept your answer as this all gets me most-to-all-the-way where I need to be.